# Java FX only updates GUI when event handler is complete

Tags: java, javafx

So I got this game built with JavaFX and I'm having some issue with the gui. When the user clicks a button, it's event handler is fired. this is psudo code for that eventhandler:

```
When button is clicked
      try to make a move
      update the board with the new move
      let the AI make a move
      update the board with the ai's move
```

The problem here is that the board is only updated after the last line has executed, so you never actually see the board after the human player have made his or hers. I have read a bit about doing gui stuff with

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {

});
```

But that doesn't seem to work for me. What am I missing here?

Edit this is my code:

```
@FXML
public void btnCell(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    disableAllButtonsDuringAITurn(board.getCells());
    Node sourceNode = (Node) actionEvent.getSource();
    String cellId = sourceNode.getId();
    int row = Character.getNumericValue(cellId.charAt(3));
    int col = Character.getNumericValue(cellId.charAt(4));
    board = treeBuilder.getFlippedBoard(board, row, col, Cell.Black, Cell.White);
    playTurn();
}


private void playTurn() {
    updateView(board.getCells());
    checkWinner();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MakeAIMove();
    updateView(board.getCells());
    updateAvailableMovesForHuman();
    checkWinner();
    if (!canHumanMakeTurn) {
        playTurn();
    }
}//Only here is the view updated.
```

Comment: How do you expect it to work from the user's point of view?  What should the user do and see?  Are any animations involved?  How long does the AI take to compute the move?

Comment: The AI can presumably make a move without any user input, potentially practically instantaneously from a user's standpoint.  So, after the user has finished all input for their turn, the system can immediately perform the calculations for the AI moves and show the board result which includes moves for both players.

Comment: To prevent this you could block user input after the user makes a move and the board is updated then run a PauseTransition to schedule an artificial delay (or run a Task if you want calculations off the JavaFX application thread) and when the Pause or Task is complete, update the board to reflect the AI move.  The effect would be user makes a move, the UI is updated, a pause occurs during which the user cannot make a new move, the AI makes a move and the board is updated, after which the user can make a new move.  Is that what you want?

Comment: What you might be missing is that UI updates are not immediate, you need to relinquish control of the JavaFX application thread for the updates to occur within a pulse.  See the [JavaFX Architecture doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1106308) on pulses to help understand this.

Comment: As already stated. When the user has clicked a button, the board should update, then call wait on the thread for maybe 2000ms and then the AI should make it's move. As it is now, the user makes his move, the AI makes his and then the board updates. Thus making it difficult for the player to see what move he did.

Comment: @nuff3 but if you cause the UI thread to wait for two seconds, how do you expect it to repaint the scene?

Comment: By updating it before the wait.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing your AI moves on the event thread in one continuous method. So JavaFX has no chance to access UI thread to make updates.

Make it in another thread.

```
new Thread(()-> { 
     AI logic; 
     Platform.runLater(() -> {
         update UI after ai move
     });
})
```

Comment: But shouldn't it be able to update the GUI before I let the AI make the move? Look at my updated question. I want it to be sequential.

Comment: @nuff3 there is only one UI thread. While you are using it nobody can't update anything. That's why it's stated everywhere to don't do any work except updating UI on that thread. In your code you even call `Thread.sleep()` on UI thread, voluntarily freezing your app for 1.5 seconds.